MPs assuming office on the day of the election
I have lately found that many seem to be of the opinion that UK MPs assume office on the day of the election, rather than on or after the date when the count for their constituency is finished and made available. This seems absurd to me since one clearly would not and should not be able to vote on bills, respond to casework or otherwise assume the duties and privilages of office until the vote tally is known. However, there appears in some quarters what I can only classify as consensus grown out of confusion between the date of election of an MP and the date of their assuming office. I'd like to clear this up if possible.
Does anyone know of any House of Commons or similarly official documention that mentions the term "assume[s/d] office" and clarifies the meaning of this, particularly when it is deemed to have occured? Any information that uses "election" or any other term by covers the same territory would also be useful. I would also be interested to know whether the taking of the oath of office and the assumption of office might perhaps be considered the same...

I'm assuming you live in a place where thay take an inordinate time to finalise the results, unlike the UK where 99% of the results are known by 0600 the next day.

@deep64blue 0600 the next day is still the next day, deep64blue, so no, that doesn't seem particularly material.

Do you have any evidence of "many" having this belief? How can they possible assume office before they know who won?

@PeterCarter 6am the next morning is before the earliest possible "business hours" that a newly elected MP could assume their duties in anyway. That means the date of the election and date it would be "safe" for them to assume office basically are the same as far as the average uninvolved citizen needs to be concerned about (nobody expects there to be a parliamentary vote at 9pm on election night), so this "confusion" you are worried about seems more like a harmless simplification.

@OrangeDog yes, I have been told it is consensus on Wikipedia and that all edits must conform to this consensus

@Ben perhaps the worry is more that on one forum it has become an established and unchangable 'truth', which one is not allowed to challenge

@OrangeDog https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Politics_of_the_United_Kingdom/Archive_17#%22Term_Start%22 or just try editing multiple dates for assumption of office on Wikipedia, and you will find a body of administrators get very angry with you.

@PeterCarter that's talking about the "term start", not when they "assume office". And as it notes, that is the date that the official UK Parliament website gives.

@OrangeDog then that appears to be a confusion in itself, because the boxouts for every UK MP on Wikipedia say 'Assumed Office' and that's certainly what I've been told by the administrators it is against consensus to edit. You can check this for yourself if you still doubt my word. You have everything necessary to corroborate what I am saying at this point.

@PeterCarter Ah, so Wikipedia has a convention to use the phrase "assumed office" to refer to the date an MP was elected rather than the date it was confirmed that they were elected, and you don't like that convention. It still does not seem like anyone has any confusion about what actually happens, this is just a disagreement about whether it's reasonable to use the phase "assumed office" to refer to the election date rather than a later event. It's probably worth putting in the question that you're trying to find out whether this distinction in language exists in technical/legal usage.

First, to clarify some of the issues raised in the question:
The election in a constituency ends when the Returning Officer declares the result. The person declared the winner becomes the Member of Parliament for that constituency. (While election results can be challenged after that, the grounds for doing so are quite narrow, so successful challenges are rare.)
Specifically, an MP's salary begins "the day after the day of the poll for the parliamentary election at which the member was elected" (Parliamentary Standards Act 2009, s4(5)).
But: "No payment of salary is to be made to a member before the member has made and subscribed the oath" (s4(6)).

This seems absurd to me since one clearly would not and should not be able to vote on bills, respond to casework or otherwise assume the duties and privileges of office until the vote tally is known.

To take the 2024 election as an example, the election took place on Thursday 4 July. Most of the results were known by the following day, with a couple of close results announced the day after that.
Parliament met for the first time the following Tuesday (9 July), for the Commons to elect their Speaker. (No vote took place this time, as Sir Lindsay Hoyle was re-elected without objection; at other times, there could have been an election for a new Speaker.) With that done, MPs then began the swearing in process, which took about a week.
The State Opening and King's Speech took place on Wed 17 July, with the debate on that lasting a few days.
The first opportunity for MPs to vote on anything took place on 22 July, that being a vote on an amendment to the King's Speech. The first vote on a bill was on 29 July - 25 days after the election, and 23 days after the final results were declared.
So the idea of MPs not being able to vote "until the vote tally is known" is moot. Even if there is a Speaker election, the general election results are determined a few days before MPs first meet in Parliament.
As for responding to casework, etc: while it takes time for MPs to move to London (for those who don't live locally), set up an office, and deal with other admin, casework continues to come in, and it appears that new MPs do get down to business as soon as they're able.

whether the taking of the oath of office and the assumption of office might perhaps be considered the same

They are not. As mentioned above, a candidate becomes an MP when their result is declared (and no earlier than the day after the election). However, they are not eligible to participate in Commons proceedings (other than the election of the Speaker), nor - crucially - to receive a salary, until they swear. Notably, Sinn Fein MPs refuse to swear allegiance to the British Monarch, so they never appear in the Commons chamber - but they are nonetheless MPs, and still deal with casework and other MP business outside the chamber.

Are elected but unsworn MPs working for free, or will they receive pay retroactively upon being sworn?

an MP's salary begins "the day after the day of the poll for the parliamentary election at which the member was elected"

@DJohnM: I believe it's retroactive.

The Sinn Fein MPs refuse to attend the chamber of the Westminster parliament, and have said they would continue to refuse to do so even if there were no oath.  As a consequence, they receive office expenses but no salary.

I believe the confusion here is that in the UK "on the day of the election" and when "the vote tally is known" are, usually, the same (or at least, vote tallies are known before the morning of the next day).
Unlike some countries, where full, confirmed, and official counts take some time to produce, but an unofficial results may be available earlier, in the UK those official results are released within hours of the polls closing. In the fastest case this year the official vote tally was announced at 11:43pm (polls closed at 10pm).
I'm not sure why the time scales are so much shorter in the UK than some other places, but it could be down to the small average geographic size of constituencies, the small size of the electorate in each constituency, the fact there is only one race per ballot paper (i.e. voters effectively do the sorting into race for the counters), the large number of volunteers drafted in, or the high levels of trust in the process that is usual in the UK.

The 11:43 result was a particularly fast declaration, though, and an outlier. Most votes were not, and are not usually, known until after 12 midnight, which is the next day.

"same geographic size of constituencies": that's not true. In 2019, sizes varied from 2.9 square miles (Islington North) to 4,930 square miles (Ross, Skye and Lochaber). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituencies_of_the_Parliament_of_the_United_Kingdom#Geographical_size_of_constituencies

@SteveMelnikoff Sorry typo. I mean "small" geographical size (compared to say, a US state).

Even ignoring the 11:43 result, the expectation is that constituencies will declare overnight, with it being something of a minor scandal that Inverness, Skye and Ross took 44 hours to declare, after 3 recounts.

RE your last paragraph, some people don't know that at general election time in the USA one ballot paper may list many races, initiatives and measures etc, while in the UK one ballot paper will only have one race (the election of the Member of Parliament for the constituency).

@Lag - good point I'll add that.

@Lag There can however be multiple separate (and usually different coloured) ballot papers given to a UK voter on one election day if (for example) a general election and local council election coincide. These are separated at the polling station and counted one race after each other at a central location, which is another difference with practice in some other countries.

@PeterCarter - unusual in that most constituencies declare later, but not particularly early for a first declaration of the night - Newcastle declared at 11.27 in 2019 and 11.01 in 2017. But if you question is "Did new MPs assume office on the 27th of June, or 28th of June, I suppose you are right, that most MPs assumed office (very early) on the 28th.

@IanSudbery your answer does not speak about the first declaration of the night. Rather you state: 'I believe the confusion here is that in the UK "on the day of the election" and when "the vote tally is known" are, usually, the same', so this is largely moot as a response and my objection to your answer remains: it is untrue.

Inverness, Skye and West Ross-shire took 44 hours to declare in 2024 not because it was close (a majority of 2160: 4.5% of votes cast) or because it is a geographically large constituency, but because in the first few attempts they could not reconcile the number of ballot papers issued with the number of ballot papers seen at the count, and those counting the votes needed some sleep.  Once he had taken the oath the following week, Angus MacDonald MP's salary would have been retrospectively backdated to Friday 5 July rather than to Saturday 6 July when the declaration was made.

@PeterCarter It really seems like the common practice is that MPs are deemed to have been actually elected on election day, even if it takes a few days to find out that they were elected by analysing the votes cast on the day. And you would rather deem them as actually elected when the results of the election are confirmed, rather than when the election actually happens. Are you seeking information about how things are done, or are you arguing for how you think they should be done?
